# How to fix Wi-Fi saying No Internet on Windows 10 even if the Wi-Fi is working fine in other devices?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, asus-laptop, wifi-driver, wireless-adapter

Every time I'm connected to a Wi-Fi, suddenly, it'll say No Internet, secured even if the Wi-Fi is working just fine. That stops me from using anything including offline LAN features like accessing my router's settings.

It goes away after turning off Wi-Fi and turning on again tho it returns after some time. Sometimes it's minutes, other times, it takes hours for the problem to show up again.

How do I fix this so I can use Wi-Fi uninterrupted?

My laptop's Wi-Fi is just fine until I've reinstalled Windows clean.

Device Manager says my driver is up to date and Windows Update doesn't find an update either. I've tried installing and uninstalling the Intel Wireless Proset listed in my laptop's drivers in the [Asus's website](https://www.asus.com/2-in-1-PCs/ASUS-VivoBook-Flip-15-TP510UQ/HelpDesk_Download/) but it doesn't do anything.

Asus TP510UQ, Windows 10.

The wireless driver currently installed in my laptop is for Realtek 8822BE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC.

```
C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig /all
```

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek 8822BE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 40-9F-38-89-69-C5
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Site-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fec0::71dc:533e:3753:80ce%1(Preferred)
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::71dc:533e:3753:80ce%7(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.254.104(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, June 12, 2019 6:47:28 PM
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, June 13, 2019 7:18:36 PM
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.254.254
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.254.254
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 88121144
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-24-84-4A-D2-40-9F-38-89-69-C5
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.254.254
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: No internet does not mean no connectivity. You can connect to the wifi but if DNS fails, it will still say no internet. You would want to check your ip configuration and ensure that it is what it is supposed to be. `ipconfig /all` is the cmd command to see it all. Especially the ip range, gateway and dns servers are important.

Comment: Yeah. Windows Troubleshooter says that but Wi-Fi is just fine in other devices. Will DNS problem also cause me to not be able to access offline sites like `192.168.254.254`. How do I fix it? I will try `ipconfig /all`

Comment: I've run `ipconfig /all`. I've added the details to the post

Comment: In case you're trying to use WEP, I have had problems with internet connectivity when using this on Windows 10. I need WEP for some old devices, but I had to switch the main router to WPA for Win10 and buy a WiFi extender to provide WEP.

Comment: WEP was recently discontinued on Windows 10.  If your using WEP and Windows 10 version 1903, that would be reason, your unable to connect to the access point.

Comment: I'm using WPA2.

Comment: Your connection seems good. Can you ping the internet both on IP address and DNS level? For example: `ping 8.8.8.8` and ping `superuser.com` ? If you cannot ping either, you have no internet connectivity at all. If you can ping the first but not the second, then it is a DNS issue. Whatever is your DNS server may need a reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my problem. I installed the RTL version of the driver to replace the former and everything's now fine.

Answer (score 0):

Having same  issue with same model.  Bought 2 of these exact same laptops.  One I kept in windows s and the other I opted out.  I was able to roll back driver to a previous version on opted out windows.  Was not able to roll back as grayed out on Windows s.

seemed to be working better.  its been a few days with no drops

my model is f510qa ASUS vivobook

Answer (score 0):

For my case it was because of my router's setting and my devices were mismatched.

When that happened, my laptop was connected to the router but it showed No Internet connection. But when I connected my laptop directly to the router using cable, there was Internet connection.

I discovered it was due to the setting on my router, and my laptop, they mismatched. My router had DHCP turned off, therefore it would require me to designate an IP on my laptop manually by going to Network & Internet Settings > Change Adapter Options > Select the WiFi Adapter > Properties > Internet Protocol Version 4 > Use the following IP address.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works,
go to control panel,
hardware and sound,
device manager,
go to view and show hidden devices,
under network adapters,
unistall or disable all wifi direct VIRTUAL adapters.
Restart.

Answer (score 0):

first change the ip and dns setting and try again.
if not work go to settings >> network and internet >>  advance network settings >> network reset >> tap reset now button and then restart your computer.
if you did not found network reset then type network reset in the search box in settings and enter into network reset menu then click on reset now and restart your computer.

Comment: if then also not work then that means there is some other problem

Answer (score 0):

A common solution worth trying:

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /flushdns
ipgonfig /renew
```

Another possibility to note: as @EdPalmer stated, there is a chance the device power state is causing the issue; this will usually manifest after coming back from Sleep/Hibernate mode for this case.  In this scenario, it should be noted that Windows is notorious for having frontend user space configurations for device power settings **not actually apply your configuration changes on the backend**.  In the case that you fall under this scenario, you would need to apply the power settings through, e.g., `cmd.exe`, `ps.exe`, `gpo`, etc.

Lastly, you can also try Intel's 8822BE driver, but do note that this will likely break your MiraCast functionality as Intel seems to have dropped support for it.

Answer (score -1):

Your wireless may be going into power saver and not waking up. You can disable power saver by opening Device Manager, bring up the properties for the wireless adapter, select the Power Management tab, then unchecking Allow the computer to turn off this device.

Comment: It's already disabled.